# get the profile url of an authenticated user instagram

Tags: java, android, instagram-api

I have developed an authentication app using instagram and below is the code snippet of it I am attempting to get the profile url of the authenticated user

```
if (requestCode == Keys.LOGIN_REQ) {
                // Make sure the request was successful
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                    instaUsername.setText("Fullname : "+bundle.getString(InstaLogin.FULLNAME)+"\n"+
                            "UserName : "+bundle.getString(InstaLogin.USERNAME)+"\n"+
                            "id : "+bundle.getString(InstaLogin.ID)+"\n"+
                            "pICTURE : "+bundle.getString(InstaLogin.PROFILE_PIC)+"\n"+
                            "access_token : "+bundle.getString(InstaLogin.ACCESS_TOKEN)+"\n"+
                            "bıo : "+bundle.getString(InstaLogin.BIO)+"\n");
                }
            }
```

please how can I get the profile url of the authenticated user with the above snippets

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make an API call providing the `ACCESS-TOKEN` as described [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_self).